# Sharepoint 2010 cannot open Word document in browser

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have a Sharepoint 2010 (Enterprise Client Access) server installed and running. I've tried to upload some document on it include Word and Excel. I open Excel document in browser, it show up but lack of tool in ribbon (only File and Data tab). But I cannot open Word document in browser. Do we have to install something on server to open those document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Office Web Apps in order for that to work.

Comment: I think that included on sharepoint product?